# Doctrine select multiple objects

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 classes that I want to select from DB using 1 query in Symfony2 Doctrine.

The first entity is `Calculation` and the second is `Polynomial`. They have 1:1 relationship:

```
/**
 * Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Calculation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Calculation")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CalculationRepository")
 */
class Calculation {
    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Polynomial")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="result_polynomial_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     **/
    private $resultPolynomial;
    //...
}
```

I have a query, that returns me all Calculations of one user:

```
public function findByUser( $user ) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
                'SELECT c
                 FROM AppBundle:User u
                    JOIN AppBundle:Polynomial p WITH u = p.user
                    JOIN AppBundle:Calculation c WITH p = c.resultPolynomial
                 WHERE u = :user
                 ORDER BY c.id'
            )
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->getResult();
}
```

And to the question... Is there a way to get resultPolynomials of the calculations in one query? If I use something like `SELECT c, c.resultPolynomial` I get error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 12 near 'resultPolynomial
': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

And if I use `foreach` cycle all calculations to get the their resultPolynomials there are many queries to the DB (1 for each calculation) and it is not good for performance if I have many calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I making a guess because you did not post your User definition nor your Polynomial definition.

I think you can make your DQL this way:

```
SELECT c, p
FROM AppBundle:User u
JOIN u.polynomial p
JOIN p.calculation c
WHERE u = :user
ORDER BY c.id
```

I guess you already defined your relations in your model so you don't need to repeat it here.